# How to get the textarea name from within SCeditor?

Tags: sceditor

I am initializing [SCEditor](https://github.com/samclarke/SCEditor) like this:

```
var mytextarea = $('textarea[name="one"])[0];

sceditor.create(mytextarea, 
{
    format: 'xhtml',
    style: '../default.min.css',
    // ...
});
```

Now I need to get the **textarea's name** from within SCEditor. My goal: After the user entered text into SCEditor or used a [custom plugin](https://www.sceditor.com/documentation/custom-plugins/), then the textarea name/id is passed with the new content to an external HTML preview field with the same ID. (There are several editors on the page.)

I haven't found any way how to get the name of the textarea (`"one"`) from within SCEditor. Here is a code snippet of a plugin that gives access to the `editor` variable:

```
// Insert-Formula Command
sceditor.command.set('insertformula', {
    // wysiswyg mode 
    exec: function(caller) {
       var editor = this;
       console.log(editor);  // cannot find the textarea's name here
```

The API does not reveal such a function: https://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/

I have tried to understand the source code (the textarea is passed as `original` in the init() function) but I could not find any way of how to return the textarea/original: https://github.com/samclarke/SCEditor/blob/master/src/lib/SCEditor.js

Then I thought I could bind the name after init with the editor's create() and access it later on, e.g.:

```
sceditor.textarea_name = "one";
```

But this does not work either.

Here is a JSFiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/kajus/0gLhtabq/10/

--

**Update:**

I can see that there is `[[Scopes]]` in the console output (jsfiddle) that holds the name. Maybe it is possible to access it?

[image: console output sceditor]

I need to get the `textarea#one` part.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a nice solution:

Pass the textarea name as the `id` in the `create()` method:

```
sceditor.create(mytextarea, 
{
    format: 'xhtml',
    style: '../default.min.css',
    // ...
    id: mytextarea_id,
});
```

And read it within the Sceditor plugin using `editor.opts.id`:

```
// Insert-Formula Command
sceditor.command.set('insertformula', {
    // wysiswyg mode 
    exec: function(caller) {
       var editor = this;
       console.log(editor.opts.id);  // cannot find the textarea's name here
```

Done